# Получить значение массива с ключём X, где X значение другого массива

Tags: php, procedure

Нужно получить из массива $point нулевой элемент, получили X, исходя из полученных данных (20), присвоить переменной $s1 элемент массива с ключём X $dom.

То есть нужно извлечь из массива point значение с ключём 0, получили цифру 20, значит нужно извлечь из массива значение с ключём 20 ('k') и поместить в переменную $s1.

Код.

```
$dom = [
'0', '1', '2', '3', '4',
'5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
];

$point = [
20, 10, 11
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Получить значение массива с ключём X, где X значение другого массива

Вот так:

```
$dom = [
'0', '1', '2', '3', '4',
'5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
];

$point = [
20, 10, 11
];

$i = 0; // Индекс
// Проверка если есть такой индекс
echo isset($point[$i]) && isset($dom[$point[$i]]) ? $dom[$point[$i]] : -99999;
```

Comment: Спасибо, ответ на вопрос нашел, практически так как я хотел, только в этом куске вот так ) ... ? $dom[$point[$i]] : -99 ...

Comment: @Robot-Mechanic не за что. исправил, благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Если эту операцию нужно выполнять чаще, чем один раз, имеет смысл предварительно получить отображение:

```
$mapped = array_map(function($index) use ($dom) {
  return $dom[$point[$index] ?? null] ?? null;
}, $point);

$i = 0;
$res = $mapped[$i] ?? null;
```

Если нет:

```
$res = $dom[$point[$i] ?? null] ?? null;
```